# How to use product full description as meta description in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, yoast

I want to use product **full description** as **meta description** in wordpress I'm using Yoast SEO. There is `%%excerpt%%` keyword to get short description. But I want full description. There is no keyword for full description. So I decide to make this using coding.

```
<?php if ( is_product() ){
    echo '<meta name="description" content="'.the_content().'">'; 
} ?>
```

I tried this and some more but no one is working. I get `%%excerpt%%` this from https://yoast.com/help/list-available-snippet-variables-yoast-seo/.

Answer (score 3):

keyword: **%%fulldes%%**    In function.php

```
// define the custom replacement callback
function get_fulldes() {
global $post;
return   $post->post_content;
}

// define the action for register yoast_variable replacments
function register_custom_yoast_variables() {
wpseo_register_var_replacement( '%%fulldes%%', 'get_fulldes', 'advanced', 'Full Description' );
}

// Add action
add_action('wpseo_register_extra_replacements', 'register_custom_yoast_variables');
```

Comment: Cool, working like a charm